# How to count the days of the month present in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have in the 6th row 12 column with the months of a year but it's an abbreviation; ex: Jan, Feb, Apr..., Dec. I want to count the days of the month in the cell just above it (7th row).

the abbreviation is a problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try: `=DAY(EOMONTH(B6&" 1, "&2023,0))`

Comment: advisable is to use dates in the header column and format as `"mmm"` if you prefer. 
(`A6` = 2023-01-01, `B6`). Than you can easily use `=eomonth(A6,0)`

Answer (score 3):

Because the number of days per month changes depending on the year (since some years are leap years), I would recommend having years attached to your month. For example, write January 2023 instead of January. You can change how the cell displays the date afterwards by right-clicking your month cell, and then clicking "Format Cells".

To count the number of days in the month, you can just find the day number of the last day of the month (or, as the code below does, takes the first day of the next month and subtracts 1).

```
=DAY(DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1) + 1, 1) - 1)
```

[image: Excel spreadsheet with the number of dates per month for 2021]

Comment: Same algorithm but a bit shorter: `=DAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,0))`  *In Excel, the 0th day of a month is the last day of the previous month*.

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to do it, here are few alternatives, that would work with <kbd>MS365</kbd> & earlier versions as well, assumption is taken that the default year is `2023`, using <kbd>EOMONTH( )</kbd> & <kbd>DAY( )</kbd> functions.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B7`

```
=DAY(EOMONTH(B6&" 1, "&2023,0))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `B8`

```
=DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2023,MONTH(B6&1),1),0))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `B9`

```
=DAY(EOMONTH(B6:M6&" 1, "&2023,0))
```

---

**Note:** The first two formulas where you need to drag right while the last one, will spill right, so no need to drag. Also instead of hardcoding the year, you can use cell reference to make it dynamic, like as below.

---

[image]

---

Here is two alternatives as suggested by **[P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)**

```
=DAY(DATE(2023,COLUMN(B1:M1),1)-1)
```

---

```
=DAY(EOMONTH(1&B6:M6&2023,0))
```

---

[image]

---

**Caveat:** Few alternatives depend on the <kbd>Locale Date Settings</kbd>

---

Comment: nice options, some are dependent on locale date notation, but the `B8` solution would work for any.
We could also choose not to reference the cell at all: `=DAY(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),COLUMN(B1:M1),1)-1)` (note that NOW() is volatile, so better to use `=DAY(DATE(2023,COLUMN(B1:M1),1)-1)` in case of 2023.

Comment: Ah, good use of `COLUMN()` function. But OP has defined the month names already. Yes I avoid using volatile functions.

Comment: I'd like to mention that my version is a tweak of the version asyndeton256 posted. I just added the COLUMN-reference as an option.

Comment: Another approach suggested @P.b --> `=DAY(EOMONTH(1&B6:M6&2023,0))`